# What ships did father serve on in Royal Fleet Auxiliary (RFA)?

Tags: 20th-century, military-records

My father Wilfred Charles Shortland served as Engineering Officer for the [Royal Fleet Auxiliary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Fleet_Auxiliary).

I am trying to find the ships when he was stationed in Malta in 1929-1934 and ships when stationed in Hong Kong or China in 1935-1939.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest and most straightforward way to obtain the information required by you on your father Wilfred Charles Shortland, might very well be to go to the Royal Fleet Auxiliary facebook page, which is administered by RN Public Relations and to ask them, as his next of kin, for the information required by you and also, if required by you, a full copy of Service Record, as his next of kin, from which to extend the information already know to you and from which to then extend back your family line, if you require to do so.